# OAuth2Authentication object deserialization (RedisTokenStore)

Tags: spring-security, jackson, spring-security-oauth2, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I'm trying to rewrite some legacy code which used `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore` to store the access tokens. I'm currently trying to use the `RedisTokenStore` instead of the previously used `InMemoryTokenStore`. The token gets generated and gets stored in Redis fine (Standalone redis configuration), however, deserialization of `OAuth2Authentication` fails with the following error:

```
Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Since there's no default constructor for this class, the deserialization and mapping to the actual object while looking up from Redis fails.

```
RedisTokenStore redisTokenStore = new RedisTokenStore(jedisConnectionFactory);
redisTokenStore.setSerializationStrategy(new StandardStringSerializationStrategy() {
        @Override    
        protected <T> T deserializeInternal(byte[] bytes, Class<T> aClass) {
            return Utilities.parse(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),aClass);
        }
                
        @Override    
        protected byte[] serializeInternal(Object o) {       
            return Objects.requireNonNull(Utilities.convert(o)).getBytes();
        }
});
this.tokenStore = redisTokenStore;



public static <T> T parse(String json, Class<T> clazz) {    
                try {        
                    return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(json, clazz);    
                } catch (IOException e) {        
                    log.error("Jackson2Json failed: " + e.getMessage());    
                }    return null;}
            
            public static String convert(Object data) {    
                try {        
                    return OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(data);    
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {        
                    log.error("Conversion failed: " + e.getMessage());    
                }    
                return null;
            }
```

How is OAuth2Authentication object reconstructed when the token is looked up from Redis? Since it does not define a default constructor, any Jackson based serializer and object mapper won't be able to deserialize it.

Again, the serialization works great (since `OAuth2Authentication` implements Serializable interface) and the token gets stored fine in Redis. It just fails when the `/oauth/check_token` is called.

What am I missing and how is this problem dealt with while storing access token in Redis?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by writing custom deserializer. It looks like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JacksonException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AuthorizationGrantTypeCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<AuthorizationGrantType> {

    @Override
    public AuthorizationGrantType deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        Root root = p.readValueAs(Root.class);
        return root != null ?  new AuthorizationGrantType(root.value) : new AuthorizationGrantType("");
    }

    private static class Root {
        public String value;
    }

    public static SimpleModule generateModule() {
        SimpleModule authGrantModule = new SimpleModule();
        authGrantModule.addDeserializer(AuthorizationGrantType.class, new AuthorizationGrantTypeCustomDeserializer());
        return authGrantModule;
    }
}
```

Then I registered deserializer in objectMapper which is later used by jackson API

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(AuthorizationGrantTypeCustomDeserializer.generateModule());
```